# How to add link into these slider

Tags: javascript, php

i want to add link into every single image on the slider. I have 7 image on the slider and i want to add different link into every different image.
How do i add the hyperlink code?
Below is my code :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        $('#first_container').vegas({
            color: '<?php echo $wa[custom_79];?>',
            delay: <?php echo $wa[custom_80];?>,
            transitionDuration: <?php echo $wa[custom_133];?>,
            timer: false,
            transition: null,
            slides: [
                <?php if ($wa[custom_82] != "" && $wa[custom_83] == "1") { $wa[custom_82] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_82]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_82];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_84] != "" && $wa[custom_85] == "1") { $wa[custom_84] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_84]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_84];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_86] != "" && $wa[custom_87] == "1") { $wa[custom_87] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_87]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_86];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_88] != "" && $wa[custom_89] == "1") { $wa[custom_89] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_89]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_88];?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_90] != "" && $wa[custom_91] == "1") { $wa[custom_91] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_91]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_90]?>'},
                <?php } 
                if ($wa[custom_92] != "" && $wa[custom_93] == "1") { $wa[custom_93] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_93]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_92]?>'},
                <?php }
                if ($wa[custom_94] != "" && $wa[custom_95] == "1") { $wa[custom_95] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $wa[custom_95]);?>
                    {src: '<?php echo $wa[custom_94];?>'},
                <?php } 
                ?>
            ],                  


            init: function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                   $('#first_container').vegas('options', 'transition', '<?php echo $wa[custom_81];?>');
                }, 1000);
            }  
        });

        $('a.previous').on('click', function () {
            $('#first_container').vegas('options', 'transition', '<?php echo $wa[custom_81];?>').vegas('previous');
            return false;
        });

        $('a.next').on('click', function () {
            $('#first_container').vegas('options', 'transition', '<?php echo $wa[custom_81];?>').vegas('next');
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I've try many ways but there is still no luck at all. I'm appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: Hi Karolos, thanks for your reply. How do i create the fiddle?

Comment: When you create your question you can add a snippet . There you can add Html,Css,Js create an example so we can help you

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm just allowed to see this Js only since i'm using a third party platform and don't have access to full code.

Comment: You have, it is called “view source code” or similar in your browser where you view the page. You should also mention what slider plugin it is you are using here. Have you checked it’s documentation already? Sliders that have their individual slides link to certain locations most often simply work by having those links be part of the original HTML structure already, so this would not even be a thing to do in the JavaScript of the slider in those cases.

Comment: It looks like vegas slider correct? According to the docs it is a background slider and what you want is a forground element so it will not work. But you can use the walk function to plug in your own action on slide change Check out the site documentation. http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/